# Error in creating custome module in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module

I am new in magento i want to create a Hello World Module i am follow many tutorial but i am always getting 404 error

My app/etc/module file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Quinchy_Demo>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Quinchy_Demo>
    </modules>
</config>
```

My Php clas file in app/code/local/Quinchy/Demo which is

```
<?php

class Quinchy_Demo_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "Hello Quinchy";
    }
}
?>
```

and config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Quinchy_Demo>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Quinchy_Demo>
    </modules>    
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <quinchy>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Quinchy_Demo</module>
                    <frontName>quinchy</frontName>
                </args>
            </quinchy>
        </routers>
    </frontend>    
</config>
```

and i calling this Module using this URL

```
127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/quinchy,
127.0.0.1/magento/quinchy/
127.0.0.1/magento/quinchy/index
```

[image: File Structure] 
please help me

Comment: You have a typo on the name of the models folder. It should say Model, not Modal.

Comment: ok i changed it but still i am facing same error

Comment: Did you check if you're getting any error in your log file (var/log/system.log)?

Comment: I just added your sample code to a fresh Magento install and it worked. Did you flush your cache?

Comment: yes i flush  and also remove all folder from var

Answer (score 1):

There must be a user  permission issue of the your file . The configuration and setup of the folder looks fine . Please check the permission .

Answer (score 1):

You code is seems to right.

- *`May be magento compiler is enable at your system.You need to
  recompile in order execute the module`*
- *`Or as rahul said,Please check file permission`*.

**To know more about compiler.please check**

http://support.createhosting.co.nz/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=49

http://alanstorm.com/magento_compiler_path

Comment: from log i am getting this 

Entity: line 2: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Simplexml\Config.php

Comment: i am running it on windows

Comment: the there some space is xml file .... Before starting `<?xml tag....` ,there are may be some space available

Comment: May be  some space issue in xml files .... Before starting <?xml tag.... ,there are  some space available.That reason it show error